# Error handling file get contents

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple script with `file_get_contents` and Facebook graph. However, there seems to be some issue with the error handling.

Here is the code I have:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/', true);

 if($json !== FALSE) {
    echo "test";
}
```

It returns the following error message:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /home/test/tst/mellemmand/test.php on line 4
```

Comment: You can't directly call this page. instead read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api , how to call api reuqest

Comment: i know but since it is just simple request there is no need to facebook library?

Comment: may they block this page by allow_url_fopen = false in php.ini